# Use OpenIE to extract relations given entities

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I want to know if it is possible to use OpenIE or if there is an available option with which I can specify the entities instead of OpenIE extracting them from Text. And given the entities it finds relation between them?

Eg. Obama was president of US. 
Input - Obama, US
Output - president of

Answer (score 0):

The `kbp` annotator can extract relations (a fixed set of relations from the KBP competition, things such as "born in").  There is documentation about using the full pipeline here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html.  One limitation of this is it won't extract general relations, but just the specific KBP ones.

No promises, but down the road we want to integrate a relation extractor into our Python code base, and make it trainable on any relation you want.  Though you would have to have training data for your specific relation type.